# Unix time -> string using C on mobile (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, c, unix-timestamp

Given a Unix time, as number of seconds since Jan 1st, 1970, how can I convert that to a human-readable string (say, ISO-8601) using C on Android and iOS? The standard library's `time.h` implementation is of no use since it only defines `time_current_millis`.

Is there a fairly simple algorithm to go from Unix time to day/month/year/hour/minute/second? If so, I could just calculate it myself rather than finding a library to support this. However, I've not been able to track down any information on the calculations.

Comment: Think I might have found a useful implementation [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,ff06f271f088f1a8,references)

Comment: `time.h` should provide functions like [`localtime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/localtime.html) or [`gmtime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gmtime.html) to break the Unix timestamp into hours, minutes, seconds, etc., then  you can use [`ctime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ctime.html) to get a string representation.

Comment: After you've used `localtime` or `gmtime` as @JohnBode suggested, use [`strftime`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime) to format the time to your requirements.  Use a format like `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"` for ISO-8601.